# Can't save compressed image using JPEG algorithm

Tags: matlab

I want to ask about compression in jpeg.
I can't save the compressed image, only the decompressed image can be saved.
Also i can't do entropy decoding.
I hope someone can help me. I'm using MATLAB R2012a. I need the file of compressed image to show that I've already compressed and can count the ratio between uncompressed and compressed image. Here are the codes :

```
function [ output_image, compressed_vector, ratio ] = jpeg_computing( input_image, q)
runtime = cputime;
n = 8; % size of blocks
dim1 = size(input_image,1); % image width
dim2 = size(input_image,2); % image height
dim3 = size(input_image,3); % number of channels
if (dim3 > 1)
    ycbcrmap = rgb2ycbcr(im2double(input_image)); % mapping, need double for DCT
else
    ycbcrmap = im2double(input_image);
end
% here you can (should) also paste downsampling of chroma components
output_image = zeros(size(input_image), 'double');
compressed_vector = 0;
[qY, qC] = get_quantization(q); % get quantization matrices
T = dctmtx(n); % DCT matrix
scale = 255; % need because DCT values of YCbCr are too small to be quantized
% Block processing functions
dct = @(block_struct) T * block_struct.data * T';
invdct = @(block_struct) T' * block_struct.data * T;
quantY = @(block_struct) round( block_struct.data./qY);
dequantY = @(block_struct) block_struct.data.*qY;
quantC = @(block_struct) round( block_struct.data./qC);
dequantC = @(block_struct) block_struct.data.*qC;
entropy_proc = @(block_struct) entropy_cod(block_struct.data, n);
%---------------------------
for ch=1:dim3
    % encoding ---------------------------
    channel = ycbcrmap(:,:,ch); % get channel
    % compute scaled forward DCT
    channel_dct = blockproc(channel, [n n], dct).*scale; 
    % quantization
    if (ch == 1)
        channel_q = blockproc(channel_dct,[n n], quantY);  % quantization for luma
    else
        channel_q = blockproc(channel_dct,[n n], quantC);  % quantization for colors
    end
    entropy_out = blockproc(channel_q,[n n], entropy_proc); % compute entropy code
    entropy_code = get_entropy(entropy_out, n, dim1, dim2); % get entropy code without
    zeros on the end

    [comp, dict] = huffman_cod(entropy_code); % huffman encoding
    compressed_vector = cat(1, compressed_vector, comp); % add to output
    % decoding ---------------------------
    dsig = reshape(huffmandeco(comp, dict), size(entropy_code)); % huffman decoding 
    if (isequal(entropy_code,dsig) ~= 1) % check if decoding is correct
        input('error in huffmandeco')
    end
    % put entropy decoding here
    % dequantization
    if (ch == 1)
        channel_q = blockproc(channel_q,[n n], dequantY);
    else
        channel_q = blockproc(channel_q,[n n], dequantC);
    end
    output_data = blockproc(channel_q./scale,[n n],invdct); % inverse DCT, scale back
    output_image(:,:,ch) = output_data(1:dim1, 1:dim2); % set output
end
%---------------------------
compressed_vector = compressed_vector(2:length(compressed_vector)); % remove first
symbol
if (dim3 > 1)
    output_image = im2uint8(ycbcr2rgb(output_image)); % back to rgb uint8
else
    output_image = im2uint8(output_image); % back to rgb uint8
end
runtime = cputime-runtime;
% compute compression ratio
% compressed_vector is binary, input image has one byte per pixel
ratio = (dim1 * dim2 * dim3 / (length(compressed_vector) /8));
tampil = guidata(gcbo);
str1 = num2str(ratio,'%1.2f %%');
str2 = num2str(runtime,'%1.2f s');
set(tampil.edit2,'String',str1);
set(tampil.edit3,'String',str2);
axes(tampil.axes_asli), imshow(input_image) % show results
axes(tampil.axes_hasil), imshow(output_image) % show results
end


function [entropy_code] = get_entropy (entropy_raw_matrix, n, dim1, dim2)
% go by tiles in loops to extract shortened entropy codes (without
% zeros on the end)
step = n-1; % poor stuff for entropy coding iterations, should be avoided
tile = entropy_raw_matrix(1:1+step, 1:1+step);
entropy_code = tile(1:find(tile(:),1,'last'));
for i=step+2:step+1:dim1-step
    for j=step+2:step+1:dim2-step
        tile = entropy_raw_matrix(i:i+step, j:j+step);
        entropy_code = cat(2, entropy_code, tile(1:find(tile(:),1,'last')));
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you have put in a lot of effort on the coding part, but not much on explaining it here.

Comment: Your problems are very, very, very, very broad.  What do you mean by you can't save the compressed image? Also, what do you mean by you can't do entropy encoding? What **specific** problems do you have?  Also, please edit your code to narrow it down to where exactly you are having problems.  Putting that much code will not garner much attention to have your problem(s) solved.

Comment: thanks for your help.
i can't save the compressed file,  as i know we can save a compressed file like *.mat or another file format before the decompress algorithm begin.

in this part i can't do entropy decoding














    if (isequal(entropy_code,dsig) ~= 1) 
        input('error in huffmandeco')
    end
    **% put entropy decoding here**
    % dequantization
    if (ch == 1)
        channel_q = blockproc(channel_q,[n n], dequantY);
    else
        channel_q = blockproc(channel_q,[n n], dequantC);